# Can I tell babel to replace an output directory?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

### The Situation

I'm working on a project in Node.js and using babel to transpile my code.  My `package.json` has a `build` command defined like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn run babel src -d lib",
  },
```

### The Problem

This transpiles fine, taking the content of `src` and outputing the result to `lib`, but there are two issues:

1. `lib` will contain old files from past transpiles even if they no longer have a matching file in `src`.
2. Babel will not rename files with a changed case if my OS is case insensitive.  For example, if I had transpiled a file named `src/Foo.js` and later renamed it to `src/foo.js` then future transpiles will still be named `lib/Foo.js`

### The Question

Can I tell babel to wipe away the contents of the `lib` directory before transpiling or do I need to just insert a `rm` into the build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel does not have functionality to do this. It is very common to use a [`rimraf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) or some other means to delete the directory before running Babel. `rm` directly is certainly also an option, but that does get more complicated if you want to support Windows too, hence the `rimraf` usage.

Answer (score 3):

Babel CLI has a flag to remove the output directory: `--delete-dir-on-start`

Couldn't find any online documentation for it, but it's listed in `babel --help`:

```
  --delete-dir-on-start                       Delete the out directory before compilation
```

Was added in [this PR back in 2017](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/6187).